# How to use SQLite - Android

Tags: android, sql, database, sqlite

Hello
I'm working on an android program that uses a database. My database is going include about 300 to 400 records.

My question is what is be best way to work with the database.
Should I create the database at run time via code and insert the records "manually" every time the program starts, or should I use an external database, that's located in the /assetes folder of the program?

If the second option is the way to go, could someone please give me an advice on how to do that, because I can't find any toturial that covers this subject.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

There's another option, which is to initialize the database the **first** time the program is launched. See the [SQLiteOpenHelper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html) class, and especially the [onCreate](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#onCreate%28android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase%29) method in that class.

Comment: To be honest this is the first time I really "touch" SQL.
 I've looked into a lot of guides, and didn't figured that what they did is what you said(I thought they created the table every time the program runs).

Answer (score 0):

[***Here is***](http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/) a tutorial for the 2nd option you mentioned.

Put your db in the asset folder and if DB does not exist in `/data/data/YOUR_PACKAGE/databases/`, it will copy the database over.

Comment: Thanks, but I used this tutorial and for some reason it doesn't work for me, and I can't find any other guide on the web on that subject for some reason.